# Which is a better choice for pointing domain name? An A-record or nameservers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

My issues is with choosing between an `A-record` pointing and changing name servers.

Here's my scenario, I have a domain from GoDaddy and I'm using *WordPress powered by Bitnami* from the AWS Marketplace to host my WordPress blog. I have an Elastic IP associated for my instance.

Should I just point the Elastic IP through the `A-record` in GoDaddy or should I configure a hosted zone from Amazon Route 53 to my domain and change the nameservers on GoDaddy?

Which one is a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the domain at Godaddy, it is wise to configure a hostede zone from amazon route53 to your domain and change the nameservers on GoDaddy to the ones of the hosted zones at route53.
Optionally you can create a CNAME record for the domain with www or anysubdomain.